# acc on unet for image segmentation is not rising when is trained on fp16

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation

i am doing some image segmentation whit deep learning, when i do it on fp32 i get val acc about 97% but when i try to train on fp16 i get stuck on 21% i've changed the learning rate and the epsilon and some times i get other acc but always stuck like this

[image]

this is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.set_policy('mixed_float16')

from tensorflow.keras import layers


def get_model(img_size, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=img_size + (3,))

    ### [First half of the network: downsampling inputs] ###

    # Entry block
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, padding="same")(inputs)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside residual

    # Blocks 1, 2, 3 are identical apart from the feature depth.
    for filters in [64, 128, 256]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, strides=2, padding="same")(
            previous_block_activation
        )
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    ### [Second half of the network: upsampling inputs] ###

    for filters in [256, 128, 64, 32]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(previous_block_activation)
        residual = layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, padding="same")(residual)
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    # Add a per-pixel classification layer
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, 3, activation="softmax", padding="same")(x)

    # Define the model
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model


# Free up RAM in case the model definition cells were run multiple times
keras.backend.clear_session()

    # Build model
    model = get_model(img_size, num_classes)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",  optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=5e-5), metrics=['acc'])



# Train the model, doing validation at the end of each epoch.
epochs = 30
model_history= model.fit(train_gen, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_gen)
```

what can be going wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `fp16`, you need to have the final layer give `fp32` output.

Change

```
outputs = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, 3, activation="softmax", padding="same")(x)
```

to

```
outputs = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, 3, padding="same")(x)
outputs = layers.Activation('softmax', dtype=tf.float32)(output)
```